# Failing to update remote repository with Git post-receive checkout: "'-f' did not match any file(s)'

Tags: git

I am trying to set up Git to update the code on a remote web server (let's call it `linode`) by simply running `git push [remote_name]`. I follow near-identical tutorials available [here](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Nilpo/8ed5e44be00d6cf21f22)).

The approach involves creating an (initially empty) work tree folder on the server (say, `/home/username/www`), plus a bare Git repository (initialized in, say, `/home/username/website.git`) with an executable post-receive hook that looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/username/www git checkout –f
```

When I push my code from my local computer to the server, that checkout fails:

```
$ git push web +master:refs/head/master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 222 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: pathspec '–f' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

The remote Git repository seems to get updated correctly: subsequent pushes return `Everything up-to-date`. However, the work tree folder `/home/username/www` remains empty.

**Solution Attempts:**

Googling the last line of this error only produces one result (in the comments of [this article](http://culttt.com/2013/04/08/how-to-deploy-wordpress-themes-with-git/)), and the solution does not apply here (I *did* make the post-receive hook executable with `chmod +x`).

I have successfully implemented the above strategy to update scripts on a scientific computing cluster (let's call it `scc`), so apparently I can set it up correctly in some circumstances. However, I'm at a loss when it comes to spotting the difference in the server configurations that lead to this problem.

One difference might be that `scc` runs Git 1.7.1, and `linode` runs 2.7.4. I admit I don't know how to install Git 1.7.1 on `linode`, as it is not available with `apt-get`. Regardless, I believe it would be desirable for this to work with 2.7.4.

Note: `linode` runs Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Totally guessing, but: check that the script on the remote (the server) really has a hyphen, ASCII 45 (http://www.asciitable.com/), and not some more exotic Unicode character like an em or en dash (unicode U+2014 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm or U+2013 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Comment: Actually more than a guess now: cut and paste of your error message shows that the character is `&#8211;`, i.e., a Unicode en-dash.

Comment: Jeez. That was it. Thanks, @torek!